# Cannot Maximize Window with JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

I made a custom Minimize button this way:

```
public MinimizeButton() {
    Button button = new Button("-");
    button.getStyleClass().clear();
    button.getStyleClass().add("actionbutton");
    button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            Stage stage = (Stage) ((Button) event.getSource()).getScene().getWindow();
            stage.setIconified(true);
        }
    });
    this.getChildren().add(button);
}
```

And I obviously called

```
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```

The button is working well.

The issue is that when I try to maximize the Window once the Stage is iconified, it takes a couple of seconds for the Window to redraw the Stage.

Any ideas on how to make the "Maximizing process" of the Window faster?

Comment: Seems ok when it is just your button that is added to a new JavaFX project. Are you sure you're not doing anything else that might cause it to take a while to redraw the window?

Comment: Right now, my program is basically composed of a couple screens without any time consuming operation. The thing is, when I maximize the window, the title bar appears followed by the elements a couple of seconds later.

Comment: Run your minimize button in a new JavaFX project and see if it still happens. If it doesn't, then it means your problem is elsewhere. If it does, perhaps it's related to your development environment (ie: old Java version).

Comment: I commented "primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);" and for some reasons, it maximizes properly when I click on my custom minimize button or on the system one...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it by using

```
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
```

instead of

```
primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
```

Comment: Thanks It really helps.